# 555 timer digital clock

Tags: digital-logic, clock, timer, 555, 5v

How would you go about connecting a 555 timer to a circuit with a 16x2 LCD display, which is already connected, to create a digital clock that counts the time? Do you have a sample of how this code would work? I have researched online and found nothing tangible.

Comment: "connecting a 555 timer to a circuit with a [...] display which is already connected" - connected to what? Do you have any schematics for this 'already connected' block, or any information we could actually use?

Comment: If that's a 16*2 character alphanumeric display, you pretty much need a microcontroller in there. At which point, throw away the 555 and use the MCU's crystal oscillator for much more precise timing. If you must avoid an MCU you could do ti with a large board of TTL, but that gets ugly pretty fast.

Comment: What about an RTC module?

Comment: Check out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kGhoRuhlxM

Comment: Great video! Exactly what I was looking for. Is there code around for this? Also is it possible to configure this to a timer, stopwatch and possibly alarm?

Comment: There is no code for that clock, it's all there in the video, including schematics. And you could modify it to do whatever you like.

Comment: Do you know of one with an RTC that includes the above features? That would result in less components and code instead of the components. The clock is a huge project! Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Then you should probably look for a Microcontroller with a all the features you need. Maybe add this information to the question so we all can know what you are really after...

Answer (score 3):

Do not, under any circumstances, attempt to use a 555 as a time-keeping clock. It's convenient and easy to design and adjust, but it is not remotely stable enough. Either make an isolated clock generator from the AC line, or use a crystal oscillator.

Comment: Yes. People frequently ignore/fail to grasp how accurate a wall clock really needs to be. An error of 1% works out to over 14 minutes a day.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use an Arduino (one with a crystal, not a ceramic resonator). You can find code examples on the net that include the LCD, and you can easily customize them.

If you want to get fancy, use a Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone and implement NTP protocol to synchronize time with a network time server using your Wifi.